# What is the updated argument for Firefox browser to run test (Selenium Java) in headless mode?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, selenium-java

I have tried to set the argument as `options.addArguments("--headless");` but it's not working. Please note that I don't want to use `setHeadless(Boolean)` method since it's deprecated now.

I have a working Chrome in headless with the following code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless=new");

driver = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().capabilities(options).create();
```

And I want to do the same with Firefox. When I use `options.addArguments("--headless");` it can not interact with the page element. I'm assuring that there are no other element to obscure the interactable element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its mentioned in Firefox options docs use "-headless" or "--headless" also works

```
addArguments("-headless")
```

complete

```
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.addArguments("-headless");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```